# How to remove multiple header row in ssrs (.rdlc) Report?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have bound the rdlc report from data set, don't know why this repeat column header. Please advise. Thanks in advance.[image: report setting in visual studio]

[image: This is output of that report]

Comment: You probably have the header row inside of the details group. Move it outside of the group and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just like BJones has mentioned in the comment above.. insert a row OUTSIDE but ABOVE the group and then copy and paste the existing header details into it. Then delete the one you have now.. done